# Why does SonarQube list files with 0% duplicates in the duplicate code section

Tags: java, duplicates, sonarqube, analysis

I am using SonarQube report analysis.

I see in the duplicate section in my SonarQube report, that a few files are listed at the end where the duplicated code is 0.0%. I am wondering why files with 0% duplicated code are listed in this section. When I open the file, I do not see any duplicated code.

If a file does not contain duplicated code, doesn't this mean it does not belong in the duplicate section?

(The same approach works for uncovered lines too, I think the same answer might help to understand code in uncovered lines section too).

Answer (score 0):

There is no good reason for this. It is a bug. Let's hope it gets fixed soon.

This issue is tracked here: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-9472